# TYPO3 10.4.12 installation blocked on second step

Tags: php, typo3, apache2, typo3-10.x

After Enviroment Overview (No Problems) i cannot continue with the installation.
It's blocked at 2/5 40%.

When I press "No Problems detected, continue with installation"
these errors are displayed in the console:

```
GET htttp://serverip/typo3/install.php?install[action]=checkDatabaseConnect net::ERR_ABORTED 500


AjaxRequest.js?bust=b0198a052e375a7df3e7d6dfe2fd1ed07efd1ed7:13

Uncaught (in promise) s.AjaxResponse {response: Response} 

install.php:1
```

- apache2 mods checked
- php.ini max_input_vars=1500 and so on (as described in System Req), changed
- no .htaccess in root of server
- no .htaccess at /var/www/domain.com/
- .htaccess in /var/www/domain.com/public generated by TYPO3

This action looks not quite finished: [action]=checkDatabaseConnect

System:

- Debian 9 (stretch)
- Apache/2.4.25
- MySQL 8.0
- PHP 7.4

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Logs

```
CRITICAL ERROR mysql_init() undefined
```

`apt-get install php7.4-mysql`

on other php Version just changing the 7.4 might do it

Answer (score 0):

I am using Docker and the `apt-get install php7.4-mysql` did not helped me with the same blocking install step on TYPO3 10.4.22 and php 7.4.

Just in case someone has the same setting, I like to post my solution:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```